# Regex how to match some closing paranthesis while excluding others in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
    CREATE TABLE "TEST_OWNER"."TEST_NOTIFY" 
    (   
    "test1" NUMBER,
    "test2" VARCHAR2 ( 200  BYTE ) ,  
    "test3" DATE,
    "test4" NUMBER,
    "test5" NUMBER(5, 6 ),
    "test6" TIMESTAMP (0 ) WITH TIME ZONE,
    "test7" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE ) 
    ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
    PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
    STORAGE(INITIAL 4545 NEXT 56565 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 898989
    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE "TEST_TABLESPACE"
    ;
ALTER TABLE MD_CMPLY_PII_MASTER ADD SKIP_FLAG CHAR(1 BYTE);
```

from the above example, I want to match the closing parenthesis which do not fall into the below conditions.

1. it should not match the closing parenthesis in lines like

   - `"test2" VARCHAR2 ( 200  BYTE),`
   - `"test5" NUMBER(5, 6 ),`
   - `"test6" TIMESTAMP (0 ) WITH TIME ZONE,`
   - ALTER TABLE MD_CMPLY_PII_MASTER ADD SKIP_FLAG CHAR(1 BYTE);

i.e., all the closing parentheses which are a part of length or precision must be avoided in matching.

From the above example, it should only match the closing parentheses of the following lines,

- `) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE`
- `BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)`

I have created regexes which detect the closing parentheses which need to be avoided. They are:

- to detect closing parentheses of `"test2" VARCHAR2 ( 200  BYTE ) ,` line:

  ```
  (?=\(\s{0,}\d+\s{0,}\w+\s{0,}(\)))
  ```

https://regex101.com/r/va73vG/1

- to detect closing parentheses of `"test5" NUMBER(5, 6 ),` line:

  ```
   (?=\d+\s{0,}(\)))
  ```

https://regex101.com/r/zDbGUa/1

I have tried combining the above two regexes, but it's still matching all closing parentheses:

```
(?=(\)))(?!(\(\s{0,}\d+\s{0,}\w+\s{0,}\)))(?!(\d+\s{0,}\)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Mtykby/1

How to get the result I want?

> *updated*

the answered regex is not working for the below ALTER statement

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD SKIP_FLAG CHAR(1 BYTE);
```

I have updated the input data in the question.what modification should I do to match the conditions to the new input data?

link : https://regex101.com/r/4Cu2wF/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the logic of matching closing parentheses that are only followed by an equal number of opening & closing parentheses. When there are more closing than opening parentheses following, it should not be matched:

[`\)(?=(\([^()]*\)|[^()])*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/4Cu2wF/1)

The `$` should denote the end of the input, not the end of the line, so don't use the `m` modifier.

The above actually finds closing parentheses which are not themselves contained in outer parentheses.

#### Alternative

If the input could be without outer parentheses (as in the `alter table` example added to your question), then the above will not work correctly.  Instead you could match whole expressions in parentheses, skipping over sub expressions which should be ignored, and then put the closing parenthesis in a capture group.

Here is how that could work in Python, given a string `str`:

```
import re
results = re.finditer(r"\(\s*[^\s\d](?:\(\s*\d[^()]*\)|(?:(\))|.))*", str, re.DOTALL)
for match in results:
    pos = match.start(1) # position of the closing parenthesis
    print "pos = ", pos, ", near: ...", str[max(0,pos-10):pos+1]
```

Comment: In the above regex how cal i avoid the selection of the following closing parenthesis in the following statement ?  ALTER TABLE test ADD col1 CHAR(1 BYTE);

Comment: See addition to answer.